# How to populate a linking table from a list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables, Country, Region and RegionCountry.  I need to populate the linking table with Countries that fall within a region.  I'd like to create some sql that takes a list of country codes (like UK, IE) and a region code( like EUR for Europe) and inserts the correct Ids into RegionCountry.  I'm relatively new to sql data transfer stuff and any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

**UPDATE**
Added sample data.

```
Country
Id
Name
Code

Region
Id
Name
Code

RegionCountry
Region_Id
Countries_Id

Country
Id                                          Name                    Code
6CEBFBAC-F1F2-444C-88E9-8BC5A8040598    Uganda                  UG
19105690-9F78-4D00-9547-50E4820AB8B2    Ukraine                 UA
988C6645-7436-4369-807B-272E42C026CB    United Arab Emirates    AE
73ACCC38-43D2-4EE4-A59C-3759CE278C78    United Kingdom          GB
AC3B8FA7-B690-4E37-9DEF-FD73EDA69167    United States           US
A1394247-C785-41E0-8550-EB610A348F5E    United States Minor Outlying Islands    UM

Region
Id                                          Name            Code
4A7678AA-2109-4455-9F0F-0F16E02FC438    Europe          EUR
7B060367-0B86-4A57-9908-1C021F697FAA    Western Asia    WEA
```

Comment: Can you provide some (useful) sample data and the desired results?  What have you tried?

Comment: @HABO  I added some sample data.  Basically I'd like to take a list, like UK,IE get their Ids and then insert the EUR id, because that's the region they are in, into the liking table.

Comment: How can you tell that UK and IE are in EUR? (obviously we know that, but the computer doesnt).  Do you have a way to select only the subset of EUR countries? (I think not, since that is the purpose of the linking table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up coming up with.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempCountries') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempCountries
GO

  SELECT *
  INTO #tempCountries
  FROM Countries
  WHERE code IN ('AL','AD','AM','AT','AZ','BY','BE','BA','BG','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','GE','DE','GR','HU','IS','IE','IT','KZ','LV','LI','LT','LU','MK','MT','MD','MC','ME','NL','NO','PL','PT','RO','RU','SM','RS','SK','SI','ES','SE','CH','TR','UA','GB')

Declare @Id uniqueidentifier
Declare @RegionId uniqueidentifier

SET @RegionId = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM dbo.Regions WHERE Code = 'EUR')

While (Select Count(*) From #tempCountries) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @Id = Id From #tempCountries

    INSERT INTO RegionCountry(Region_Id,Countries_Id)
    VALUES (@RegionId,@Id)

    Delete #tempCountries Where Id = @Id

End
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand better, you have a list of data you are going to insert, and you already know the region code at the time you are inserting. How are you going to execute the SQL, who has that list?

First, there is no reason for a linking table in this case, since a country can only be in one region. Just put the region ID as a field on the country table.

However, the linking table is needed if a country can belong to more than one region

The easiest thing is just do a loop over the list, and for each entry insert two records (the region and the country)

This however may have performance impacts depending on how many countries you are adding, where you might want to do a bulk insert instead. This will all depend on what language you are using to do the work

If you are trying to do it directly against the database, a stored proc or something could take the list, but the syntax for that will differ depending on what database you are using.

Comment: We can't say for certain that a country can only be in one region.. The UK could be in an EU region, a British Isles region, a Western Europe region, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. First I'm creating the list, but I'm having difficulty finding a concrete list of countries that are considered "Europe" vs "Eastern Europe" so that's why I did the linking table.

Comment: The linking table will allow this, but you wont be able to magically populate it with the right values - you will have to say what region each country is in.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @RegionID INT  

 -- INPUT Data  
 DECLARE @RegionCode VARCHAR(50)  
 DECLARE @Countries VARCHAR(500)

 SET @RegionCode = 'EUR'  
 SET @Countries = 'UK,IE'

 SELECT @RegionID = Id  
 FROM dbo.Region  
 WHERE Code = @RegionCode  

 INSERT INTO dbo.RegionCountry  
 SELECT @RegionID,Id  
 FROM dbo.Country C  
 INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@Countries, ',') S  
 ON C.Code = S.items

 --Dependency:  
 -- Create this function to split the given string  
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (  
    @String VARCHAR(8000)  
    ,@Delimiter CHAR(1)
    )
 RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items VARCHAR(8000))
 AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @idx INT
    DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT @idx = 1

    IF len(@String) < 1
        OR @String IS NULL
        RETURN

    WHILE @idx != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @idx = charindex(@Delimiter, @String)

        IF @idx != 0
            SET @slice = left(@String, @idx - 1)
        ELSE
            SET @slice = @String

        IF (len(@slice) > 0)
            INSERT INTO @temptable (Items)
            VALUES (@slice)

        SET @String = right(@String, len(@String) - @idx)

        IF len(@String) = 0
            BREAK
    END

    RETURN
 END
 -- Source for split function : http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx
```